# about the Trivial Homology Group within a Torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $T$ be a torus. We will consider its $\Delta$-complexes to find Homology Groups of it. Consider the sequence:

$$ 0 \longrightarrow \Delta_2^{T} \longrightarrow_{\delta_2} \Delta_1^{T} \longrightarrow_{\delta_1} \Delta_0^{T} \longrightarrow_{\delta_0} 0 $$

where $\delta_i$ are boundary homomorphisms from $\Delta_{i}^{T}$ to $\Delta_{i-1}^{T}$ each.

I am in confusion with $H_0(T)$ which is $Ker(\delta_0)$, and it is *known* to be $H_0(T) = \mathbb{Z}$

Why do we have exactly the set $\mathbb{Z}$ in question? is it because we need *homotopy classes* of paths *modulo identification of first & end points*?

Thanks for further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H_0(T)$ is not $\text{Kernel}(\delta_0)$. Instead, it is
$$H_0(T) = \text{Kernel}(\delta_0) \, / \ \text{Image}(\delta_1)
$$

Regarding your question about homotopy classes of paths, this particular computation does not have anything to do with homotopy classes of paths. Instead, it's just about doing the linear algebra computations that are needed in order to compute the right hand side of the above equation.

But there is a general theorem which is perhaps what you are asking about: If a space $X$ is path connected then $H_0(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: **1.** for $H_0(T)$ you are right. I skipped the detail, and told the answer for this exact case. Here, $Im(\delta_1)$ is $0$. **2.** for the other, what you say about paths being involved in $H_0(T)$, you didn't quite get the question. indeed, in the boundary homomorphism of order $0$ we don't have paths no more. I actually don't get the apparently trivial conclusion about $H_0(T)$ being countable. indeed I guess the theorem you mention can exactly help me. Can you show me which one?

Comment: I gave the full statement of that theorem, and here it is again: If a space $X$ is path connected, then $H_0(X)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$. This is often one of the very first theorems proved about singular homology groups, where the proof is very easy. It is actually a little harder to prove for $\Delta$-complex homology.

Comment: i found the theorem you mentioned. i want the proof for it. (in my ref book, it is skipped.) or you show me how many different lines one can draw between two points $A$ and $B$? (they are distinct or not is not the point.)

Comment: That could be a good question to ask, although not in a comment to an answer to another question. But you should search on the site first. Actually, looking under the "Related" heading on this page I see this link: [the 0-th homology of a simplicial complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/988256/the-0-th-homology-of-a-simplical-complex?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you. the question in the link is totally good, i havent found any yet. and the questions may seem different at first glance but it was intended to show the point i was looking for.